# Why is browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo undefined in Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to get which OS the user runs in a Firefox WebExtensions addon.

There's a simple example on [Mozilla API Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getPlatformInfo).

According to this documentation, the function browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo() should help me getting platform OS but it doesn't work and seems to be undefined.

I'm testing it on Firefox 57.0.2 64-Bit installed on Windows 10 64-Bit.

Why is browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo undefined?

Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Addon",
    "version": "2.0",

    "description": "Test Addon",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "clipboardWrite"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
console.log("browser.runtime:");
console.log(browser.runtime);
console.log("browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo:");
console.log(browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo);

function gotPlatformInfo(info) {
    console.log(info.os);
}

// The following line breaks code execution
var gettingInfo = browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo();
gettingInfo.then(gotPlatformInfo);
```

Comment: What context are you executing that code? Background? Content script?

Comment: i'm executing it in content script. sorry for not giving enough info in the first place. i've revised my question and added more details.

Comment: tested in background and it works! thanks for directing me to the right way.